# Java: Collections.unmodifiedMap vs Collections.checkedMap

Tags: java, dictionary, collections

If I understand correctly, `Collections.checkedMap` will return a map that will throw `ClassCastException` when subject to any type of change like addition, deletion or modification of an entry.

If that is achieved, then why should we use `Collections.unmodifiedMap()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misunderstand.  `Collections.checkedMap` throws a `ClassCastException` when a key or value *of the wrong type* is put into the `Map`.  `Collections.unmodifiableMap` throws an `UnsupportedOperationException` when *anything* is put or removed from the `Map`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Louis. I got this question when I read the following lines from the API documentation: _'Returns a dynamically typesafe view of the specified map. Any attempt to insert a mapping whose key or value have the wrong type will result in an immediate ClassCastException. Similarly, any attempt to modify the value currently associated with a key will result in an immediate ClassCastException, whether the modification is attempted directly through the map itself, or through a Map.Entry instance obtained from the map's entry set view.'_

Comment: Reference: [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#checkedMap(java.util.Map,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class)]